# TypeError: TypeError: (0, _reactRedux.useSelector) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am working on `useSelector` of `react-redux` inside my React Native application, I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: TypeError: (0, _reactRedux.useSelector) is not a function.`

My Code is :

`import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';`

`const availableMeals = useSelector(state => state.meals.filteredMeals);`

as per the official documentation, this is the simplest use of `useSelector` but I am getting this error.

Previously, I was getting another error related to `Redux` in my project but it got resolved automatically over a night, so is this issue related to some cache ?

How can I resolve this?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummy-data';
import MealList from '../components/MealList';

function CategoryMealScreen(props) {
    const catId = props.navigation.getParam('categoryId');

    const availableMeals = useSelector(state => state.meals.filteredMeals);

    const displayedMeals = availableMeals.filter(meal => meal.categoryIds.indexOf(catId) >= 0);

    return <MealList listData={displayedMeals} navigation={props.navigation} />;
};

CategoryMealScreen.navigationOptions = navigationData => {
    //console.log(navigationData);
    const catId = navigationData.navigation.getParam('categoryId');
    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find(cat => cat.id === catId);

    return {
        headerTitle: selectedCategory.name,
    };
};

export default CategoryMealScreen;
```

Comment: Could you post your code with codepen or some live editor ?

Comment: Make sure you have react-redux v7.1.0 or above

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri My react-redux version is 7.1.3 still the error persists.

Comment: @MaulikSakhida Please check this : https://codepen.io/chetannik44/pen/LYYmLgR?editors=0010#0

Comment: is meals key defined in your route reducer like this? const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  meals: ...
});

Comment: I was importing it from the wrong package (from "redux-form") which was giving me that same error

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded `react-redux` version from `^5.1.1` to `^7.1.1` in `package.json` file.

This caused an upstream dependency error when I run;

> npm install

I fixed that by upgrading `react` version from `16.8.0` to `16.8.3` in `package.json` file.

After that, I was able to install both dependencies and stopped receiving error below;

```
TypeError: TypeError: (0, _reactRedux.useSelector) is not a function
```

Comment: react-redux first add hooks on v7.1.0, so you should update you react-redux

Answer (score 1):

useSelector() hook only takes functions as input, so to resolve your issue you have to make a function that will handle your logic and then call it in useSelector.
Here is an example:

This is an es6 function

```
    const getMeals(state) => {
return state.meals.filteredMeals;
}
```

And then pass your function into useSelector like this:

```
const availableMeals = useSelector(getMeals(myState));
```

You can put this function(getMeals) in your **current component** or even put it in **your reducer**.

Comment: `state => state.meals.filteredMeals` is already a function, though.

Comment: @Tolokoban `state.meals.filteredMeals` looks like a single value that was stored in the state.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was importing useSelector from react...

```
import React, { useSelector } from 'react';
```

, but it actually is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you verified that react >= 16.8.3 and react-redux >= 7.1.1 try the solution below.
The workaround for me was to install `metro` package version 0.56.0 .

Via npm:
`npm install metro@0.56.0`

Via yarn
`yarn add metro@0.56.0`

Answer (score 0):

As per my issue,
It is resolved by clearing the cache of jest with the following command.

```
npm run jest --clearCache
```